# java xml sign add X509IssuerSerial (name and number)

Tags: java, xml, sign

I don't know how to add a X509IssuerName and X509IssuerSerialNumber to my signed xml from my certificate.

I am using Java 1.6.

This is my code:

```
KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
p12.load(new FileInputStream("c:/cert/mycert.p12"),"PASSWORD".toCharArray());
Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
System.out.println("Cert alias:" + alias);
Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("PASSWORD".toCharArray()));
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();   
KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
List x509Content = new ArrayList();  
x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()); 
X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());
XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
signature.sign(dsc);
```

What I must add to `x509Content` list to get something like this in my X509Data node?

```
<X509IssuerSerial>
   <X509IssuerName>CN=Tax CA Test,O=state-institutions,C=SI</X509IssuerName>
   <X509SerialNumber>4723074879886330622</X509SerialNumber>
</X509IssuerSerial>
```

I got the source code from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html

Also if I try to run

```
cert.getSerialNumber();
```

will produce exception
 java.lang.ClassCastException: content[1] is not a valid X509Data type

Comment: Solved.. I have converted p12 into pfx with internet explorer... and added pfx into p12 keystore.. after that I have done X509IssuerSerial x509IssuerSerial = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(),cert.getSerialNumber() );

Answer (score 2):

```
final List<Object> x509Content = new ArrayList<Object>();
final X509IssuerSerial issuer = kifactory.newX509IssuerSerial(x509ce.getIssuerX500Principal().getName(),x509ce.getSerialNumber());
x509Content.add(issuer);
```